# Where has the "new" button gone?

Tags: discussion, help

I just get 'active' etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wherever it went, it is now back. Was it a hack? What can we infer from that, if it was?

- that people are hacking me and/or stack exchange

EDIT

it's gone again.

EDIT

it's back again.